# Powerpoint with Apache POI custom XML

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, docx4j

I am trying to create a custom Xml document for a powerpoint presentation.

```
private static void addCustomXmlPart(OPCPackage opcPackage, String xml) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException {
        final PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/customXml/item1.xml");
        opcPackage.getParts();
        final PackagePart part = opcPackage.createPart(partName, ContentTypes.PLAIN_OLD_XML);
        final OutputStream outputStream = part.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(xml.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        part.addRelationship(partName, TargetMode.INTERNAL, PackageRelationshipTypes.CUSTOM_XML);
}
```

now I want to create the part "/customXml/itemProps1.xml" i.e

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<ns1:datastoreItem ns1:itemID="{43c3fce5-a408-416d-b13f-3a332456c532}" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/customXml"/>
```

How can i create the datastoreItem with poi? i've seen that in docx4j there is 
the `createDatastoreItem()` method of the `ObjectFactory`  class

```
    CustomXmlDataStoragePropertiesPart part = new CustomXmlDataStoragePropertiesPart();
    org.docx4j.customXmlProperties.ObjectFactory of = new org.docx4j.customXmlProperties.ObjectFactory();
    DatastoreItem dsi = of.createDatastoreItem();
```

there is something similar in Apache POI library, or alternatively there is an other way to create a custom XML for powerpoint in POI?

Comment: Why not just repeat the code you have for doing `/customXml/item1.xml` to add the new item props part as well?

Comment: Cause i don't know how to insert the datastoreitem, i can do by hand but it's not a clean solution, i think.